# Unhandled Errors not showing from Visual Studio 2010 Debugger (x86 mode)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We have a user that is using VS2010 and whenever he has an unhandled exception it doesn't show up when he is using his Visual Studio Debugger (x86 mode). It seems the debugger is just ignoring the exception. It doesn't happen on other developer's machines. I don't have much time to look through settings on his machine as I am pretty confident it has to be a problem with his VS as we are all using the same solution/projects and it works for everyone else. Any ideas what could be wrong with this one machine? (I would love to reinstall VS on that machine but we don't have the time to do it)

This doesn't happen JUST in the "Load" method. It happens in EVERY method. The link pointed to doesn't solve this problem as I had tried everything there to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

In top menu click on Debug -> Exceptions.
Check the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox (in the Thrown column).

Comment: Here is a [screenshot of it](http://www.codesmiles.com/image.axd?picture=debug-exceptions_thumb.png)

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was in a hurry to get 1000th point, yay!

Comment: checked... Looked good.

Comment: Can also be got to by pressing CTRL + ALT + E

Comment: Dennis, does you comment mean that the checkbox is checked and it is still not stopping on the exception?

Comment: yes, the checkbox is checked